# when I use the method find_image_occurrence of Appium with python, always occurred TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, image, appium, contains

```
import base64

def img_base64(img_path):
    if os.path.exists(img_path):
        with open(img_path, 'rb') as f_obj:
            image_data = f_obj.read()
            base64_d = base64.b64encode(image_data)
    return base64_d

master.save_screenshot(".\\screenshots\\test.png")

full_screenshot_base64 = img_base64(".\\screenshots\\test.png")
partial_screenshot_base64 = img_base64(".\\resource\\images\\suit_head.png")

master.update_settings({"getMatchedImageResult": True})
master.update_settings({"fixImageTemplateScale": True})

master.find_image_occurrence(base64_full_image=full_screenshot_base64, base64_partial_image=partial_screenshot_base64, visuallze=True)
```

When I run above python code, error message is:

```
raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

How should I solve this problem? Please help me, thank you!

According to the method description, the type of the parameter needs to be bytes, but the prompt is: Object of type bytes is not `JSON` serializable.

Comment: My local environment is:
appium driver list:
✔ Listing available drivers
- uiautomator2@2.29.3 [installed (npm)]
- xcuitest@5.6.0 [installed (npm)]
- mac2 [not installed]
- espresso [not installed]
- safari [not installed]
- gecko [not installed]
- chromium [not installed]   appium plugin list
✔ Listing available plugins
- images@2.1.2 [installed (npm)]
- execute-driver@3.0.15 [installed (npm)]
- relaxed-caps@1.0.5 [installed (npm)]
- universal-xml@1.0.9 [installed (npm)]

Comment: appium plugin list
✔ Listing available plugins
- images@2.1.2 [installed (npm)]
- execute-driver@3.0.15 [installed (npm)]
- relaxed-caps@1.0.5 [installed (npm)]
- universal-xml@1.0.9 [installed (npm)]

Comment: appium 2.1.3, Python 3.11.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you never ended up solving this, I encountered a similar problem and the documentation around the implementation unfortunately leaves a bit to be desired.

The trick for me was using `.decode("ascii")`.
Additionally, don't forget to start your Appium server (whether manually or programmatically) with the `--use-plugins=images` argument.

As an example, here is how I implemented it (the code isn't complete):

```
def load_image_base64(path: str):
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        return base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode("ascii")

def compare_images(driver):
    reference = load_image_base64("./reference_images/menu_icon.png")
    target = load_image_base64("./runtime/dashboard_screenshot.png")
    driver.find_image_occurrence(base64_partial_image=target, base64_full_image=reference)
```

Hope this helps (you or anyone else in the future)!